# Vaildate user by label value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I am validating my users with header variables that I display in my .net application and my question is how can I validate that the user that is on the on the current page is allowed to proceed to any other pages.

[image]

I want to check the name from an array or names and if they are not listen then it will redirect them to an error page letting them know they do not have access.

I was going to take the path of sql authentication but that would just require an additional login page and since I already check the header variables I thought I could just go about this way. Any help regarding this would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You should never trust ANY data sent from the client to your server. The header-variables can easily be modified to represent anything. One could easily forge the header to spoof themself for being somebody else (like admin in worst case).

You should really consider some sort of authentication that requires a combination of username + password, I'm afraid.

If you REALLY want to rely on the headers though, add a header that identifies themself, like `X-USERNAME:CSharpDev4Evr`, and then just parse that one and match against the array on back-end.

I don't know any C#.NET, but here's a JavaScript-snippet showing the principle:

```
var headerUsername = "CSharpDev4Evr";
var validUsernames = ["Eric", "CSharpDev4Evr", "Stackoverflow", "root"];

// Check if we are in the array
// Re-direct if we're not
if (validUsernames.indexOf(headerUsername) === -1)
    window.location = 'error.html';

// Proceed with other authenticated stuff here
// ...
```